# autohotkey use a return value imagesearch and click

Tags: autohotkey

I have a function:

```
NormalRand(x,y,int=1) {
Loop 12
{
    Random, var,0.0,1
    Num+=var
    }
    norm := (int) ? Round((y+x)/2+((Num-6)*(y-x))/6) : (y+x)/2+((Num-6)*(y-x))/6
    Return norm < x ? x : norm > y ? y : norm
```

}

I have an imagesearch:

```
ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenWidth, *50 Okay.jpg
If ErrorLevel = 0
{
    xCord = NormalRand(%FoundX%-10,%FoundX%+10)
    yCord = NormalRand(%FoundY%-10,%FoundY%+10)
    MsgBox, 4,, Found the image at %xCord% %yCord%
    Click, %xCord%, %yCord% Left, 1
    Sleep, 2000
}
```

I am trying to use the NormalRand function to distribute my clicks around the buttons so they are harder to detect within the program I will use this with. However, when i try to sent the cords to the `click` it doens't work. When i test it with msgbox i get this output `Found the image at NormalRand(391-10,391+10) NormalRand(676-10,676+10)`

I can't seem to figure out how to get it to send the numbers instead of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we have here, is misuse, and probably also unintentional use, of the legacy syntax.
Lets look at these two lines:

```
xCord = NormalRand(%FoundX%-10,%FoundX%+10)
yCord = NormalRand(%FoundY%-10,%FoundY%+10)
```

You're actually assigning text to those variables, not calling a function.
See this as an example:

```
xCord = NormalRand(%FoundX%-10,%FoundX%+10)
yCord = NormalRand(%FoundY%-10,%FoundY%+10)

MsgBox, % xCord "`n" yCord
```

For legacy syntax you're referencing the FoundX and FoundY variables correctly by wrapping them around `%`, but you're not doing that for the function name.
So in legacy syntax you'd do this:

```
xCord = %NormalRand%(%FoundX%-10,%FoundX%+10)
yCord = %NormalRand%(%FoundY%-10,%FoundY%+10)
```

However, please stop using legacy syntax. It's so ancient, bad and very different compared to other programming languages you maybe have experienced.
Expression syntax is what you want to use, so instead of legacy `=`, we're using `:=` to assign an expression to our variables. (`=` is never ever used!)
In expression syntax your function calls look normal and nice:

```
xCord := NormalRand(FoundX-10, FoundX+10)
yCord := NormalRand(FoundY-10, FoundY+10)
```

And to preach even more about legacy syntax, you're also using it on the if-statement. To not use the legacy if-statement, use `if ()`.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I have also switched over from the legacy syntax based on your suggestion!

Comment: Good stuff, I recommend giving [this](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm) a read. Also, noticed your click command being a bit weird. You're missing a comma, but any case, specifying `Left, 1` does nothing for you, that can be left out.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Will read through it. appreciate it. removed the `Left, 1`